# SVN Merge Procedure

Tags: svn, merge

I have three folders in the repository and have checked out working copies of each.

The folder names are 6010, 6012, and 6010_debug.

The folders 6010 and 6012 are vendor releases. The folder 6010_debug is where I have added a bunch of debugging code.

The goal is to create 6012_debug such that it is the culmination of the changes made by the vendor from 6010 to 6012 (bug fixes, etc), plus the additions I have made to 6010 resulting in 6010_debug.

So, whether it is the diff between 6010 and 6012 that will be applied to 6010_debug, or the diff between 6010 and 6010_debug that will be applied to 6012, the desired end result is 6012 with all the debug code.

What would be the steps involved using TortoiseSVN 1.9?

Comment: Why not compare 6012 and 6010_debug? Since you have written 6010_debug, it will be easier for you to merge.

Comment: Why not 'Compare'? Or 'Merge'? There is no 'Compare' in TortoiseSVN 1.9. Using the 6010_debug working copy folder, I select Merge, 'Merge a range', From: '6012', 'specific range' is blank, then Merge, I get "6012 must be ancestrally related to 6010_debug." When going the other way, using the 6012 working copy folder, selecting all revisions from 6010_debug, I get "6010_debug must be ancestrally related to 6012." So, **Merge a range of revisions** doesn't work. Some - not all - combinations of **Merge two different trees** (experiments made prior to posting) did not give desired results.